# Missing many dlls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

Somehow, I have no idea how, put the project in very weird state where many dll from MVC are missing. Take a look on image, how can I restore them ? 
I tried with NuGet

```
install-package aspnetmvc
```

but it doesn't help

[image]

Comment: did you change the target framework version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Update-Package -Reinstall` this is the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those are packages.

### 1.

Open up Package Manager settings by Going to **Tools -> Options...** (VS2012) then **Package Manager -> General** and tick both checkboxes.

[image: Package Manager Settings]

### 2.

Enable NuGet Package Restore

[image: Enable NuGet Package Restore]

### 3.

Build your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that you changed the target framework before this happened. Remove the references and add them back using NuGet. That will solve this problem

Comment: do you see how many are missing, and should I restore one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade You target Framework version 
Enable NuGet Package Restore.

Go to Package Manager Console and type this

```
Update-Package
```

Hit Enter.

After this Rebuild you Project/Solution and all should be good.

Comment: he term 'Update-Packages' is not recognized

Comment: Its Update-Package. Check this for reference. http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Package%20Manager%20Console%20Command%20Reference%20%28v1.3%29